# Is there any way to use an instance variable in another method?

Tags: java, junit, instance-variables

Lets say I have a method that defines and assigns a value to a variable. I want to somehow be able to use that variable and its value within another method.

I don't want to pass the variable as an argument because I'm running a selenium test, and there are multiple test methods that depends on that one method - which means it will only execute if one of those test methods (that depends on it) is executed.

I've tried using accessors/mutators to assign the id to a class variable, but it doesn't seem to work

e.g

```
String mainId;

public void setID(String s) {
    mainId = s;
}

public String getID() {
    return mainId;
}  

@Test
public void doSomething() {
    String numeric = this.randomNumeric();
    String id = "D1234" + numeric;
    this.setID(id);

    ... // do something with that id number
}

@Test (dependsOnMethod = {"doSomething"})
public void somethingA() {
    ...sendKeys(this.getID()); // do something with that id - e.g search the database to see if that id was added correctly
}

@Test (dependsOnMethod = {"doSomething"})
public void somethingB() {
    ... // do something else with that id
}
```

Comment: This is because JUnit creates a new instance of your test class for each test (method). Not sure what the best practice is here, but have you tried using a static variable instead?

Comment: You should probably be doing common setup (like determining the `mainId` value) in a pre-test method annotated with `@Before`.

Comment: static doesn't work and when I debug the ...sendKeys(this.getID()) part, it returns null

Comment: If `mainId` becomes static, then you would not access it using `this` instance. Static members belong to the class, not any particular instance of that class. So it could be accessed via `MyClassName.mainId` or just `mainId` in internal class code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sharing logic/variables between `@Test` methods, you can either use an instance method annotated with `@Before`, which will be invoked once before every `@Test` method, or a static method annotated with `@BeforeClass`, which will be invoked only once for the entire test class before any `@Test` methods run.

In your scenario, assuming you need to generate the `mainId` value once and reuse the same value across multiple `@Test` methods, you would need to use `@BeforeClass` and store the value as a static variable, like so:

```
private static String mainId;

@BeforeClass
public static void init() { //must be public static void
    String numeric = randomNumeric();
    mainId = "D1234" + numeric;
}

@Test
public void somethingA() {
    //use mainId (note that it belongs to class, not this instance)
    //...
}

//other tests...
```

Note that changing `mainId` and the `doSomething` logic to be static requires you to change the `randomNumeric` method to be static as well.